# Could not find file mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc

Hi when i try to run sakila database example from netbeans site
https://netbeans.org/projects/samples/downloads/download/Samples/JavaEE/DVDStoreEE6.zip

i have some problem showing following in my n output windows 
of NetBeans 7.3.Beta2

```
ant -f "C:\\Users\\unknown\\Documents\\DVDStoreEE6 (1)"
-DforceRedeploy=false -Ddirectory.deployment.supported=true -Dnb.wait.for.caches=true run init: deps-module-jar: deps-ear-jar: deps-jar: library-inclusion-in-archive: C:\Users\unknown\Documents\DVDStoreEE6 (1)\nbproject\build-impl.xml:995: Warning: Could not find file C:\Applications\NetBeans\NetBeans Dev
201107270600.app\Contents\Resources\NetBeans\ide\modules\ext\mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar to copy. BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Can any one guide me why this problem is occurring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to download **mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar** and then set your classpath.
here the [link to download](http://code.google.com/p/nearbuy/downloads/detail?name=mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar&can=2&q=)

Comment: Thanks for answar i download this from this link but where to install it when i click on this jar file nothing happen...what to do next?

Comment: create lib folder in your project folder paste the downloaded jar their and then open your netbeans goto your project right click on library option open that browse your project folder then goto lib folder you have created open that then click on that jar you have pasted their then click ok

Comment: @KishorJoshi if any problem message me

Comment: No Thanks Ashish Now it is solved thanks so much @Ashish

Answer (score 1):

In case if you have already included the 'mysql-connector-java' jar file and are still facing the same error like me, here is what you can do.
When the error is displayed in the output window click on the blue link that is displayed.
Eg:

```
 C:\Users\Username\NetbeansProjects\ProjectName\nbproject\build-impl.xml
```

Within that remove the below line,

```
<copyfiles files="${file.reference.org-netbeans-modules-db-mysql.jar}" todir="${build.web.dir}/WEB-INF/lib"/>
```

Hope this helps.