# Could not find MySQL Connector in Netbeans

Tags: mysql, web, netbeans, connector

I transferred my web project from another laptop to another. Installed every jar files needed. But when i run the project, this error comes out.

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\Inventory\Inventory\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1013:
Warning: Could not find file G:\Downloads 
from Chrome\commons-fileupload-1.4-src.zip to copy.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Ive tried :

[Could not find file mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20832271/could-not-find-file-mysql-connector-java-5-1-13-bin-jar/20835732#20835732)

I have mysql connector installed on my libraries. So i tried Saumil answer. But i could not find the line in my `build-impl.xml` which is this:

```
copyfiles files="${file.reference.org-netbeans-modules-db-mysql.jar}" 
todir="${build.web.dir}/WEB-INF/lib"
```

So since i couldn't find the line that Saumil suggested in my `build-impl.xml`, i have no idea how to fix this. I am not sure which line should i remove to fix this.

Comment: Error says you are using "commons-fileupload" libraries in path "G:\Downloads 
from Chrome",and they cannot find in your other laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. All i did was clicking the blue link on the error line, and remove all "copyfiles files" line and rerun the project. Thanks :D